# How can use a loop instead of repeatedly putting in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list created with random integers that I want to print in to a table of 10 integers by 10 integers.
The best way I came up with to do this is by manually putting in print a certain range of elements over and over again until it is displayed as a table, however, I would like to use a loop instead. I am unsure of how to do this though.

This is the code I used:

```
import random
def main():
    list1 = []
    for count in range(100):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        list1.append(number)
    print(list1[0:9])
    print(list1[10:19])
    print(list1[20:29])
    print(list1[30:39])
    print(list1[40:49])
    print(list1[50:59])
    print(list1[60:69])
    print(list1[70:79])
    print(list1[80:89])
    print(list1[90:99])

    
main()
```

This is the output I get and would like to receive something like this:

```
[35, 9, 53, 1, 13, 67, 48, 1, 38]
[60, 43, 2, 95, 91, 33, 76, 45, 15]
[17, 69, 63, 38, 49, 94, 77, 94, 65]
[36, 14, 73, 3, 33, 41, 12, 71, 5]
[5, 63, 86, 98, 77, 88, 41, 73, 43]
[33, 37, 52, 50, 77, 97, 61, 6, 82]
[65, 31, 60, 57, 91, 9, 50, 50, 7]
[23, 94, 6, 21, 13, 99, 80, 18, 28]
[9, 15, 18, 20, 47, 93, 88, 17, 17]
[93, 97, 11, 40, 45, 34, 10, 55, 61]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you can do that!

```py
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    print(list1[i:i+9])
```

Enjoy! Hopefully it works. There's probably a better way out there, but you'll be fine with this.

Comment: You're welcome! To "close" this question, do you mind accepting my answer (tick)? Thanks!